# Spark history web UI dont show spark job on running spark job in yarn mode from client machine

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I have a Hadoop cluster. I am trying to run my spark job using spark-submit command from my local machine.
So i copied the Hadoop config files to my local machine,installed spark and set env variables in my local machine.
After executing the command

```
spark-submit --deploy-mode yarn wordcount.py
```

It ran successfully.
But to my surprise when I tried to open Spark history server web UI using `start-history-server.sh` from remote cluster machine.Then it don't show any spark job instead on running `start-history-server.sh` from my local machine shows the spark job.

So my question is the spark job is triggered from local machine to be launched in remote cluster. How come my local machine shows spark job status in spark history web UI?

How can I make it possible the remote cluster to show spark job status.
Note, I don't want to ssh to remote cluster .I need to run the spark job from my local machine.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you're using this exact command?

```
spark-submit --deploy-mode yarn wordcount.py
```

Because this should fail with some error like:

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: --deploy-mode must be either "client" or "cluster"

I suspect your issue is that your `--deploy-mode` variable is not what you think it is, and it defaults to `client` mode. That makes the driver run on your local machine and so both the history server logs and the web-ui run on your local machine.

Comment: Thanks.That was a typo error. I was using client as a deploy mode and hence driver was running in local machine.